# How to get 'static pure virtual' functionality in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm programming Chess, and I wanted to use abstract classes for each different piece:

```
enum class Player { Black=0, White }

class Piece {
protected:
    Player side;
    ...
public:
    // I'm using a 1D array of ints to store the board,
    // cast() returns a list of positions where the piece can go.
    virtual std::vector<int> cast() = 0;
    ...
}

class Bishop {
public:
    // implements cast()
    std::vector<int> cast() override;
    ...
}
```

This works fine if I, for example wanted to work out every position when the current player's king is not in check. If the king is in check, however, the approach I want to use to work out the possible moves in the position is to try to move the king (works), or work out the squares where piece can go that will prevent check, and `cast(int position)` with that position with all the different types of pieces and check if there is a piece that can block check. Hence why I want to make `cast` `static` but also `virtual`.

Comment: It is not interesting to read about your check problem. What is your programming problem? I have no idea what you are asking for! BTW: You can't have static & virtual as static has no object and virtual is to give a method for a given object.

Comment: There isn't _static pure virtual_ in C++.  You'll probably need a free standing function that looks at the derived type of the object and then dispatches to another free standing function or to an appropriate class static function.

Comment: `static virtual` makes no sense unless we start to get classes as objects (which won't be happening)

Comment: A couple of design flaws here: (1) the piece itself should not really know which side it's on. That's a property of the *collection* of pieces on that side. (2) `cast` is flawed. E.g. a bishop might be taken, but then reintroduced due to queening but this time on the other colour.

Comment: @Bathsheba I strongly disagree. E.g if you just replicate the physical game: Each piece has a color which is clearly a property of the physical object. This is purely a matter of taste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible.

With a virtual function, the exact function called depends on the type of the object you call the function on.

With a static member function, there is no object on which the call is made, only a type.

As such, having both makes little sense. How would the compiler know which derived type you mean to call?